# HTML Hover Code over Image (Mailchimp Email Template)

Tags: html, hover, mailchimp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zt9Y.jpg)

How can I enter a Hover HTML Code over an image in a simple Mailchimp email template?

Comment: do you mean something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean adding a href link when clicking image?

For example,

`<a href="https://www.html.com"><img src=".jpg"/></a>`

Answer (score 0):

To hover over an image I have provided a reference code.Refer links for more understanding:https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-change-image-on-hover-with-css.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="My image" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">My Image</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```